# XMLElement combined with XMLAttribute to create new object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a simple XML:

```
<Tag>
   <Preferences type="NumberPreferences">
     <Name>Number</Name>
   </Preferences>
   <Preferences type="TagPrefenreces">
     <Name>Tag1</Name>
   </Preferences>
</Tag>
```

Instead of having similar to:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Tag {
   @XmlElement(name = "Preferences")
   private List<Preferences> preferences;
}
```

I would like to have:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Tag {
   // any annotation
   private Preferences numberPreferences;
   // any annotation
   private Preferences tagPreferences;
}
```

Is there any easy way to achieve this by combining xml element with xml attribute?

I am happy with any solution that is not super complicated. In other case, I will workaround with it and possibly just remap this object to different object.

Comment: You might be able to if you make Preferences an abstract class and 2 implementation classes that will contain the default mapping behavior for each element

Comment: Probably possible with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`. But if your file is simple then I would just read it in with JDOM or similar and manually map it to your domain object like you said. Using an xml type adapter is basically manual mapping anyway.